# how to programmatically restart WAMP or Apache?

Tags: wamp

As part of some automated deploy + test scripts I use to verify programming done for a site, I have some scripts which update Apache's config files.  I would like to programmatically restart WAMP so the changes take effect.  Is there a good way to do this?

The scripts are powershell.

This is whats in my apache bin folder:

```
iconv
ab.exe
abs.exe
ApacheMonitor.exe
apr_dbd_odbc-1.dll
apr_ldap-1.dll
dbmmanage.pl
htcacheclean.exe
htdbm.exe
htdigest.exe
htpasswd.exe
httpd.exe
httxt2dbm.exe
libapr-1.dll
libapriconv-1.dll
libaprutil-1.dll
libeay32.dll
libhttpd.dll
logresolve.exe
openssl.exe
php.ini
php5isapi.dll
php5ts.dll
rotatelogs.exe
ssleay32.dll
wintty.exe
zlib1.dll
```

Comment: Add `apachectl -k graceful` at the end of your script? Maybe I should ask first what kind of script it is...

Comment: Its a powershell script.  I don't see a apachectl.exe anywhere.

Comment: It's in the apache bin folder.  (It might be named `apache2ctl`.)

Comment: httpd -k restart returns "[error] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : No installed service named "Apache2.2"."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this command to restart Wamp, Apache, MySQL services:

To start services

```
NET START wampapache
NET START wampmysqld
```

To stop services

```
NET STOP wampapache
NET STOP wampmysqld
```

For **mariaDB**, replace `wampmysqld` with `wampmariadb`.

For **64 bits**: append 64 to the service names.

Comment: For 64 bit, you should use `wampapache64` and `wampmysqld64`

Answer (score 4):

Simple execute command:

httpd.exe -k restart

**ps. this is my wathdog for windows**

```
@echo off
:loop

timeout /t 30 /nobreak 
REM . 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq php-cgi.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "php-cgi.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto Process_NotFound


tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq httpd.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "httpd.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto Process_NotFound


goto loop



:Process_NotFound

TASKKILL /F /IM php-cgi.exe
TASKKILL /F /IM httpd.exe

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2
Apache -k start
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3
cls
php.exe -r "$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server.name/'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   curl_exec($ch);"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3
ab.exe -n 10 -c 3 http://server.name/

goto loop
```

Answer (score 3):

> 1. CTRL+R -> Type (Command) -> Right Mouse -> Run Administrator
> 2. Go to your wamp aptech bin folder  eg : D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin>
> 3. Type httpd.exe -d (Show All apache parameter command )
> 4. httpd.exe -k start -n wampapache64
> 5. httpd.exe -k stop -n wampapache64
> 6. httpd.exe -k restart -n wampapache64

**Graphical Instruction :**

> Step First:

[image]

> Step Second:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing some code to find the "wampapache" service and restarting it.

```
public static void ResetApache()
{
    ServiceUtil.RestartService("wampapache", 10000);
}
```

...

```
public class ServiceUtil
{
    public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int msTimeout)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);

        int startTicks = Environment.TickCount;
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(msTimeout);

        if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped
            && service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)
        {
            service.Stop();
        }

        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

        int midTicks = Environment.TickCount;
        timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(msTimeout - (midTicks - startTicks));

        service.Start();
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);

        //int finalTicks = Environment.TickCount;
        //var totalTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(finalTicks - startTicks);

        //Console.WriteLine("Reseting process took " + (totalTime.TotalMilliseconds/1000.0) + " seconds.");
    }
}
```